# How to implement a really optional field in protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a proto describing an event which might happen monthly, yearly or at specific date. The basic structure for that is:

```
enum PeriodType {
  MONTHLY = 1;
  YEARLY = 2;
  SPECIFIC_DATE = 3;
}

message Event {
  PeriodType period_type = 1;
  ...
}
```

But there should be a way to specify on which date that happens. So I've made the following proto:

```
message Event {
  PeriodType period_type = 1;
  Date period_specific_date = 2;
  ...
}
```

That solution was banned during our internal code review. The reason is that "proto should not contain fields which are used only when there is a particular value in another field". I need to rewrite that somehow so that when `event` has `period_type == MONTHLY` it shouldn't be possible to call `event.getPeriodSpecificDate()`. How can I do that?

A possible solution is to make like that:

```
message Event {
  message Period {
    PeriodType period_type = 1;
  }
  message PeriodWithDate {
    Period period = 1;
    Date period_specific_date = 2;
  }
  oneof period {
    Period period_without_date = 1;
    PeriodWithDate period_with_date = 2;
  }
  ...
}
```

But that doesn't really solve the problem and looks like a terrible overkill. Is there any other way?

Comment: Ask the person who banned it in your code review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a date is given, you don't really need the PeriodType.
So you could do this:

```
enum RegularPeriod
{
    MONTHLY = 1;
    YEARLY = 2;
}
oneof period
{
    RegularPeriod regular = 1;
    Date specific_date = 2;
}
```

Comment: In my case after discussion we've returned to "banned" variant and I definitely recommend it for anyone who has the same requirements. But your solution is an excellent answer for the original question

Answer (score 1):

> That solution was banned during our internal code review. The reason is that "proto should not contain fields which are used only when there is a particular value in another field".

Tell your reviewers that I'm the author of Protocol Buffers v2 and that I think this rule is unrealistic. While it is tempting to enforce everything in the type system, in practice the Protobuf type system is nowhere near expressive enough to make this kind of hard rule. In real-world use it is in fact very common to have fields with documented constraints like "this field should only be present if field X has value Y", and that's really OK.

With that said, *in this particular case*, @jpa's answer is reasonable. It has tradeoffs: you'll now have multiple levels of branching in your code, which could be ugly and may get uglier if your protocol gets more complicated. But it does manage to express all constraints in the type system.

(Don't accept my answer, accept @jpa's.)

Comment: Thank you for clarification!